# How to verify status of DNS service such as Quad9?

Tags: dns

I have been using the [Quad9](https://www.quad9.net) DNS servers provided by IBM et al. as a security measure (they blacklist unsafe domains).

After working well for over a year, I suddenly had some strange Internet access problems at home, yesterday and today. At least some problems were **immediately resolved by switching from 9.9.9.9 to 8.8.8.8** (Google's public DNS server) as the assigned DNS server. The problems re-appear immediately if I switch back to 9.9.9.9 address.

Is there some way to know if Quad9 DNS servers are functional? Or perhaps are under denial-of-service attack?

Their web site has no "Status" page that I can find. Is there any kind of "internet weather" resources that can help with learning of DNS disruption problems?

Comment: *Is there some way to know if Quad9 DNS servers are functional?* - Other than by simply attempting to use them, it seems unlikely. Regarding the existence of some kind of "internet weather" resource, that seems unlikely as well, simply because there are likely too many DNS providers to count. If you want to check sites manually, you can try [googling for services that show a site's status](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+it+up), but that may be the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to test a DNS resolver is to query it for records which you already know the answers for, and to compare the results you get with the results you expect.  This could be just a small matter of programming in any scripting language of your choice (provided it can use tools like `host` or `nslookup`, or that it can do DNS queries directly or through some library).

Note that if you're using some foreign DNS resolver service, no matter which, whenever there's a problem with that service you will likely have to discontinue using that service in order to find and connect to any kind of third-party status reporting service (unless you can do so with a direct IP address).